# Wordpress - Let users select USER ROLE on Sign Up

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added some functions to my `function.php` and it works really great. The only problem I see is that when the users Sign Up, its shown twice in "Simple History". That means my function are triggering registration twice?

I am still learning, some help will be highly appreciated.

```
// URL set USER ROLE

add_action('user_register', 'register_role');

function register_role($user_id, $password="", $meta=array()) {

    $userdata = array();
    $userdata['ID'] = $user_id;
    $userdata['role'] = $_POST['role'];

    //only allow if user role is my_role

    //allow other roles
    if ( ($userdata['role'] == "vip_member") or ($userdata['role'] == "free_member") ) {
        wp_update_user($userdata);
    }
}

add_action('register_form','show_role_field');
function show_role_field(){ ?>
<p>
    <label style="display: block; margin-bottom: 5px;">Role
        <select id="role" name="role" class="input">
            <option value='vip_member'>VIP Member</option>
            <option value='free_member'>Free Member</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</p>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Actually your `register_role` is not being executed twice, instead it's could be `register_form` hook once and `register_role` hook second time.

Comment: @Recovering is it possible to improve my code? Make this 2 hooks to 1 or any suggestion?

Comment: I think it's the right way, [Same example on Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form).

Comment: [Check this](http://thecodegenie.com/tutorials/wordpress-user-registration-and-login-forms/), if it helps.